# Using an alert to choose between image gallery or camera in UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift3, uialertview

I have an UIImagePickerController that works, but I wanted to let the user decide whether he shoots the image or picks it from library. So this is my code trying to do it with alert:

```
    @IBAction func cameraButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose one of the following:", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { action in
            self.picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { action in
        self.picker.sourceType = .camera
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However, once I click on one of the actions in the alert, nothing happens, it just gets out of the alert but not presenting my picker

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by presenting inside the action like this:

```
    @IBAction func cameraButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose one of the following:", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { action in
            self.picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { action in
        self.picker.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```